# new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream());

Tags: java, sockets, server, objectinputstream

When I call this constructor in another class that class' GUI freezes, what am i doing wrong? It doesn't print any Excepction StackTrace....  Thanks!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private String username;

    public Client(Socket socket, String username) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            this.input = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
            this.output = new ObjectOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    this.username = username;
}
```

This isn't a duplicate as the answer to the other one didn't solve my GUI blocking...

Comment: Don't do a blocking action on your GUI thread. `new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream())` is a potentially block action because of the read and you're doing it on your GUI thread. Don't.

Comment: I have to do another Thread then? @SotiriosDelimanolis